# Why do my OCMock expects and stubs fail in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ocmock

I have some simple mock objects with some stubs and expectations set up.  When I run my tests on the iOS 4.3 simulator, everything passes.  When I run on iOS 5, I get "unexpected method invoked" failures.  As an example case, I have a method `- (void) foo: (NSString *) bar` that I set up an expectation for and then run.  The result is

```
unexpected method invoked: foo:@"foobar" 
                 expected: foo:@"foobar"
```

Any one know why this is happening, or how to fix it?  The tests themselves are perfectly fine, and have been working for months in iOS 4.

Comment: I reported this a while back at http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=233&sid=371fd3946d71048deedae278e1e3eeaa. It doesn't seem like any progress has been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the latest version of OCMock from [Github](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock) on iOS 5 without any problems. There have been some recent additions to this repository, so it's quite possible that the problems you're experiencing have been fixed in the latest version.

Comment: I compiled all the latest OCMock code from source directly in my project, and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry only saw this now. It has been fixed for a while

https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/commit/db6f27041efc507ae6ab92721e2f7bbbbd14c28b

**Update:** The newly released version 2.0 of OCMock contains this fix. So, you don't have to build from source if you don't want to.

Comment: I do appreciate you responding Erik.  Thanks for clarifying the issue.